# Need help modifying script to use individual files, instead of all files at once

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a very simple rework of this script I inherited.   I have no previous experience with batch files and needed to modify this already working script in a very simple manner.

Currently, this script does the following:
- Monitors a folder and looks to see if there are files in it
- If there are, it executes a FTP transfer via command line
- Then, it moves the files into a archive folder created and named with the current timestamp and writes something to a text log file
- If there are no files, the script exits and does nothing.

As of now, the script is looking for, processing, and moving all the files at once.  I was looking to see if I could be pointed int the right direction with help on how to modify the script so that it does each file one by one, instead of using *.* everywhere.   Ultimately, I think all I need to do is figure out how to do the loop correctly and read/store the filenames to use as variables instead of using *.*   Any help would be appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Set count of files = 0
SET X=0

:: Set timestamp for processed folders
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.%TIME:~9,2%

:: If more than 0 files exist begin ftp and file archival otherwise exit
FOR %%i IN (c:\Encoded_HL7_Vanderbilt\*.*) DO IF EXIST %%i (SET X=1) 
IF [%X%] gtr [0]  (cd\..\..

cd\"Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error switching to ftp program directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
exit)

wsftppro -s local:C:\Encoded_HL7_Vanderbilt\*.* -d Vandy!Vanderbilt:/incoming/ 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error transmitting file to ftp server>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
exit)

md "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%1\%TIMESTAMP%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error creating archive directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
exit)


move "C:\Encoded_HL7_Vanderbilt\*.*" "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt%1\%TIMESTAMP%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error moving files to archive directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
exit)) ELSE (exit)

echo %TIMESTAMP% File transfer completed successfully>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.success.txt
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a walk around the park: if any file generates an error then it will stop processing further files.

```
@ECHO OFF

set "folder=%~1"

:: Set timestamp for processed folders
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.%TIME:~9,2%

:: If more than 0 files exist begin ftp and file archival otherwise exit
FOR %%a IN (c:\Encoded_HL7_Vanderbilt\*.*) DO (

cd\"Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error switching to ftp program directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)

wsftppro -s local:%%a -d Vandy!Vanderbilt:/incoming/ 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error transmitting "%%a" file to ftp server>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)

md "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%" 2>nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error creating archive directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)


move "%%a" "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error moving "%%a" file to archive directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)

)

echo %TIMESTAMP% File transfers completed successfully or no files were found>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.success.txt
exit

:done 
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.   One thing, though.  I tested it a few times and it successfully reads in first file, transfers it, creates the archive folder with a timestamp, then moves it.   When it gets to the second file, it reads it, transfers it, but errors our creating the archive folder.   Is it possible that it is trying to create the archive folder for the 2nd file that it technically has the same timestamp as the first one and cannot create it?

Comment: Thanks again, it looks like it works.  I moved the lines where it created the archive folder to be outside the loop.   This way, it creates 1 timestamp, and 1 arvhive folder with the timestamp as a name, then processess all the files and moves them to this folder.

Comment: `wsftppro -s local:"%%a"` <--- Try adding quotes where I've put them there and if it works then it should protect the batch file from long path names, if the source folder ever changes, and long filenames, if the files ever have them.  The `2>nul` in the `MD` command was there to eliminate the harmless error messages when the folder already exists.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it might work for you:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL

:: Set count of files = 0
SET /a count=0

:: Set timestamp for processed folders
set "TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.%TIME:~9,2%"

cd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12"  || (
    echo %TIMESTAMP% Error switching to ftp program directory>"E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt"
    exit /b 1
)
md "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%1\%TIMESTAMP%" || (
    echo %TIMESTAMP% Error creating archive directory>"E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt"
    exit /b 1
)

:: If more than 0 files exist begin ftp and file archival otherwise exit
FOR %%i IN (c:\Encoded_HL7_Vanderbilt\*) DO (
    set /a count+=1

    REM I don't know the wsftppro command line parameters, pls. check the man page
    wsftppro -s local:"%%~i" -d Vandy!Vanderbilt:/incoming/ || (
        echo %TIMESTAMP% Error transmitting file to ftp server>"E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt"
        exit /b 1
    )
    move "%%~i" "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%1\%TIMESTAMP%" || (
        echo %TIMESTAMP% Error moving files to archive directory>"E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt"
        exit /b 1
    )
) 

if %count% equ 0 (
    rd "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%1\%TIMESTAMP%" 2>nul
    exit /b 1
)

echo %TIMESTAMP% File transfer completed successfully>"E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%1\%TIMESTAMP%.success.txt"
```